# Specifying the Rise and Fall Time for clocks

Tags: verilog, xilinx-ise, vivado

I am trying to simulate a D-Flip Flop for Metastability. With ideal clocks generation in Xilinx ISE and Vivado, I cannot see the metastability phenomenon. I need to specify the clock with Rise and Fall time for the metastability to occur. I couldn't find a way to do it in Xilinx. Any suggestions on this are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide rise time, fall time & turn off time for any gate delays.

```
#(1,2,3) not n1 (clk_out, clk_in)
```

Here

- 1 - Rise Time
- 2 - Fall Time
- 3 - Turnoff Time

Comment: Thanks Karan but how to do it for clocks and other signals? As metastability has a lot to do with clocks.

Comment: I don't understand your point. But this expression can be applied for any logic.

Comment: @Swastika you can use `#(1, 2, 3) buf ckBuf (ckOut, ckIn)` between your clock generator and dut input.

Comment: @Karan I thought the delays work for logic gates only.